# Find all row combinations which sum elements equal to any given number

Tags: python, algorithm, combinatorics

It works fine, but it is slow.

Could anybody help make this faster?

```
import itertools

from decorators import timer
from settings import MENU, CASH


class Cocktail(object):
    def __init__(self, group, name, sell, count=0):
        self.group = group
        self.name = name
        self.sell = sell
        self.count = count


class Check(object):
    def __init__(self, cash, menu=MENU):
        self.__cash = cash
        self.__cheapest_cocktail = 10000
        self.__menu = self.__read_menu(menu)
        self.__matrix = self.__create_matrix()
        self.correct = []

    def __read_menu(self, menu):
        result = []
        for group in menu:
            key = group.keys()[0]
            for cocktail in group[key]:
                if self.__cheapest_cocktail > cocktail['sell']:
                    self.__cheapest_cocktail = cocktail['sell']

                result.append(Cocktail(
                    key,
                    cocktail['name'],
                    cocktail['sell'],
                ))

        return result

    def __create_matrix(self):
        result = []
        max_count = self.__cash // self.__cheapest_cocktail
        for cocktail in self.__menu:
            row = []
            for i in range(0, max_count):
                row.append(Cocktail(
                    cocktail.group,
                    cocktail.name,
                    cocktail.sell,
                    i
                ))

            result.append(row)
        return result

    def find_combinations(self):
        for check in itertools.product(*self.__matrix):
            if sum([(c.sell * c.count) for c in check]) == self.__cash:
                self.correct.append(check)


check = Check(CASH)
check.find_combinations()
check.__matrix size 80x25
```

Comment: Hello, could you please add some more information about what you are trying to achieve here? Thanks

Comment: I try find all row combinations which sum elements equal any given number.

Comment: What is `check.__matrix size 80x25` after your code? Is it part of the code? Can you give a sample Input and output of your program so it can be easier to understand?

Comment: Probably not worth an answer but I think you should have a look at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0 (I have no idea how many times I've posted a link to this video on this SE).

Comment: I believe you are trying to solve the knapsack problem, here is an example: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knapsack_Problem/Python

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Python Performace Tips](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips) and search for list comprehension. As far as I can understand your code you can use it.

An example would be this function.

```
def __create_matrix(self):
    max_count = self.__cash // self.__cheapest_cocktail
    return [ [Cocktail(cocktail.group,cocktail.name,cocktail.sell,i)
         for i in xrange(0, max_count)] for cocktail in self._menu]
```

You don't need to create a list if you are not using it elsewhere. In the `find_combinations` function you can avoid the overhead of list creation because you are only interested in the sum of the elements.

```
def find_combinations(self):
    for check in itertools.product(*self.__matrix):
        if sum((c.sell * c.count) for c in check) == self.__cash:
            self.correct.append(check)
```

I think there is a bug in your code. You are using a class`Cocktail` but using `cocktail` in your code. I understand they are different but I think you have messed up **C** with **c** in your code in the `__read_menu` function. It is confusing whether or not you have messed it up.

That is all I can think of because I don't understand what the code is doing unless. Please edit your question to add sample input and output.